# xy + overrightarrow = error

Tags: errors, xy-pic

M(non-)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[ \xymatrix{ \overrightarrow{C} } \]
\end{document}
```

produces "ERROR: Illegal parameter number in definition of \lastprentry@@.".  Any ideas?

Comment: For me, adding `\usepackage{amsmath}` fixes things: I suspect this is simply assumed by `xy`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add braces around the symbol, which is often the remedy to weird error messages from Xy-pic macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[ \xymatrix{ {\overrightarrow{C}} } \]
\end{document}
```

Or just add an empty group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[ \xymatrix{ {}\overrightarrow{C} } \]
\end{document}
```

The problem is that `\overrightarrow`, being the first item in an alignment cell, gets expanded to

```
\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr <...>}
```

and this confuses the parsing commands of Xy-pic. This doesn't happen if a brace is found before `\overrightarrow`, because it will be expanded later. This doesn't happen also when `amsmath` is loaded, because the definition of `\overrightarrow` given by `amsmath` is “safer”.