# Using \overrightarrow in a glossary

Tags: glossaries, arrowwithtext

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{acr1}{ $\overrightarrow{ abc }$ }{ It does not work }
\newacronym{acr2}{ABC}{It works!}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
\acrshort{acr1}
\acrshort{acr2}
\printglossary[type=acronym,title=Tests]


\end{document}
```

The above code results in multiple errors of type: `Illegal parameter number in definition of ...`

I have already tried the solutions proposed in:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191166/219526
but none of them has solved my problem.

Is it possible to use `\overrightarrow` in a glossary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\protect`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{acr1}{$\protect\overrightarrow{abc}$}{Works}
\newacronym{acr2}{ABC}{It works!}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
\acrshort{acr1}
\acrshort{acr2}
\printglossary[type=acronym,title=Tests]


\end{document}
```

[image]